Trigger Google Maps advanced marker glick from HTML link
I'm in the process of updating an old Google Maps script to use the new advanced marker format.  Everything is working fine in terms of dynamically generating the markers based on an array of locations, displaying them on the map, and making them clickable with an info window.  The one piece of functionality I can't get to translate is the ability to click an HTML link and have it trigger a marker click so the corresponding info window opens.
For context, this is part of a directory.  When a user searches, a map is displayed above the search results with all the markers, and then there's also a text listing of the results below.  Within each search result, we want a "View on map" link, where if a user clicks the link it will trigger a click on the corresponding marker and display the info window.
With the old version of the markers, we were able to push each marker onto an array called mapMarkers as it was created, and then we had this function tied to the HTML links that all had a class of goToMarker:
$('.goToMarker').on('click', function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(mapMarkers[$(this).data('markerindex')], 'click');
});

That same approach isn't working for me with the new version.  Here's my current code (this is in a C# Razor view, and some values are being populated from variables; I also realize I eventually need a way to tie the result ID back to its specific marker, but for now I'm just targeting the first marker with index 0 across the board to try to get a proof of concept):
        <script>
            (g => { var h, a, k, p = "The Google Maps JavaScript API", c = "google", l = "importLibrary", q = "__ib__", m = document, b = window; b = b[c] || (b[c] = {}); var d = b.maps || (b.maps = {}), r = new Set, e = new URLSearchParams, u = () => h || (h = new Promise(async (f, n) => { await (a = m.createElement("script")); e.set("libraries", [...r] + ""); for (k in g) e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g, t => "_" + t[0].toLowerCase()), g[k]); e.set("callback", c + ".maps." + q); a.src = `https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?` + e; d[q] = f; a.onerror = () => h = n(Error(p + " could not load.")); a.nonce = m.querySelector("script[nonce]") ?.nonce || ""; m.head.append(a) })); d[l] ? console.warn(p + " only loads once. Ignoring:", g) : d[l] = (f, ...n) => r.add(f) && u().then(() => d[l](f, ...n)) })
                ({ key:'@(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleMapsAPIKey"])', v: "weekly" });
        </script>

        <script>
            var mapMarkers = [];
            let map;

            async function initMap() {
                const { Map, InfoWindow } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
                const { AdvancedMarkerElement, PinElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

                const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: { lat: @Model.searchConfigMap.centerLat, lng: @Model.searchConfigMap.centerLong },
                    zoom: 6,
                    minZoom: 1,
                    maxZoom: 20,
                    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
                    gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
                    mapId: 'AMRPA_REHAB_HOSPITALS',
                });

                //array of hospital locations
                const arrHospitals = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrHospitals));

                //create shared info window
                const infoWindow = new InfoWindow();

                //fontawesome icon for glyph
                const icon = document.createElement("div");
                icon.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pizza-slice fa-lg"></i>';

                //create markers
                arrHospitals.forEach(({ position, title, infoText }, i) => {
                    const pin = new PinElement({
                        glyphColor: "#FFFFFF",
                        background: "#9d2235",
                        borderColor: "#9d2235",
                        scale: .8,
                    });

                    const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
                        position,
                        map,
                        title: `${title}`,
                        content: pin.element,
                        gmpClickable: true,
                    });

                    //add click listener for each marker and set up info window.
                    marker.addListener("click", ({ domEvent, latLng }) => {
                        const { target } = domEvent;

                        infoWindow.close();
                        //infoWindow.setContent(marker.content);
                        infoWindow.setContent(buildContent(infoText));
                        infoWindow.open(marker.map, marker);
                    });

                    mapMarkers.push(marker);
                });
            }

            initMap();

            function buildContent(infoText) {
                const content = document.createElement("div");
                content.classList.add('infoText');
                content.innerHTML = infoText;

                return content;
            }

            function goToMarker() {
                try {
                    //alert('clicked!');
                    alert(mapMarkers.length);
                    alert(mapMarkers[0]);
                    //mapMarkers[0].click();
                    google.maps.event.trigger(mapMarkers[0], 'click');
                }
                catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        </script>

When I click on one of the HTML links, I get this error in the console:
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'domEvent' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
    at aR.<anonymous> (rehabhospitaldirectory:820:52)
    at _.Kk [as trigger] (main.js:141:94)
    at goToMarker (rehabhospitaldirectory:849:39)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (rehabhospitaldirectory:887:58)

I also tried just triggering a click on the mapMarkers[0] element directly, and that didn't error, but it also didn't do anything.
Any help is much appreciated!

When you ask a question here and people try to help, you're expected to provide feedack!

It works for me.
The error is in the goToMarker function but according to the code you shared you are not calling that function anywhere.
The trigger via the jQuery selector should work. My guess is that you are still calling that goToMarker function from the HTML link itself which wouldn't make sense, but this part of the code is missing in your question.


async function initMap() {
  // Request needed libraries.
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: 37.42,
      lng: -122.1
    },
    zoom: 14,
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
  });

  const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map,
    position: {
      lat: 37.42,
      lng: -122.1
    },
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    alert('CLICKED')
  })

  const link = document.getElementById('link')

  link.addEventListener('click', () => {
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click')
  })
}

initMap();
#map {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 150px;
}
<a id="link" href="#">CLICK ME</a>
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- prettier-ignore -->
<script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk", v: "weekly"});</script>



